# command l to access downloads directory in raspian

Tags: linux, command-line, directory, raspberry-pi3

lines I have tried:

```
cd ~/downloads
cd /home/pi/downloads
cd ~/user/home/downloads
ls ~/downloads
cd ~./downloads
```

If I use the nano command the screen will come up but if Try to change directory it says `"no such file or directory"`. Don't laugh its probably simple but I'm new to Linux and trying to learn command lines.

Comment: Download directory for what? It's probably application specific so you should look at the program you expect to have performed the download for information on the location it uses. `ls`, `ls -la`, `cd`, and `pwd` are otherwise good commands for getting your bearings in a *nix system.

Comment: Are you sure that a "downloads" directory exists? Are you certain that it is spelled `downloads` and not `Downloads`?